# Remove comments from bundled js and css files

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, cassette

I am using [Cassette](http://getcassette.net) for Asp.Net to bundle and minify my js and css files. The issue is it leaves all the comments in file headers. I want to remove them since they contain some delicate information about the code for the development team.

I understand that it's for reference lines and License information protection, but that really should be disabled on demand (leaving the refence lines).

Is this possible? I am going through the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that on Cassette, but you can try to use the System.Web.Optimization included on ASP.NET. You don't need an external library to accomplish this. [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: Actually, I do. I would check out the link I provided in the question. You may also get addicted to it like most of the people :)